# Toggle overlay parent accessibility preserving children accessibility preferences

Tags: ios, swiftui, accessibility

Let's assume that an iOS app presents some content via `overlay` modifier or in `ZStack`. This way accessibility focus (e.g. when user enables voice over) is available for both elements of parent content and presented content.

I could use `accessibilityHidden(isOverlayPresented)` modifier on the underlying view to fix this, but in that case when `isOverlayPresented` is `false`, SwiftUI ignores the parameter passed to `accessibilityHidden` modifier applied to child views.

In the example below accessibility rotor ignores "Text 1" and "Text 2" labels when "Text 3" is presented, but it does not ignore "Text 1" when "Text 3" is not presented, despite `.accessibilityHidden(true)` being applied.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isOverlayPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            ZStack {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Text("Text 1")
                        .accessibilityHidden(true)
                    Text("Text 2")
                    
                }
                // don't want the view to be accessible when overlay is presented
                .accessibilityHidden(isOverlayPresented)
                
                if isOverlayPresented {
                    Text("Text 3")
                        .padding(30)
                        .background(.yellow)
                }
            }
            
            Button(isOverlayPresented ? "Show" : "Hide") {
                isOverlayPresented.toggle()
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
    }
}
```

"Text 1" being always ignored by accessibility should be expected behavior in my opinion. If I implemented that with SwiftUI environment, I would do something like this, so that `true` value passed from parent could not override child preference.

```swift
extension View {
    func accessibilityHidden(_ hidden: Bool) -> some View {
        transformEnvironment(\.accessibilityHidden) { hiddenByParent in 
            hidden = hidden || hiddenByParent
        }
    }
}
```

I also could use conditional modifier, that would not be applied when parameter value is false, but conditional modifiers are evil in my opinion, especially when are applied to a complex views (e.g. root view of some flow).

Is there a good way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Since you applied accessibilityHidden to a container it rewrites inside modifier you applied to Text("Text1"), and because when the background with Text3 is not shown `isOverlayPresented == false`, hence line `.accessibilityHidden(isOverlayPresented)` says that all VStack's children should not have hidden accessibility.

This happens, because, containers are not accessibility elements by default. So you need to specify that they're

To achieve this, you need to apply `.accessibilityElement(children: .contain)`, before `.accessibilityHidden(isOverlayPresented)`. This way we tell that VStack is accessibility element, and it contains its children, so we can interact with them

The code would look next way:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isOverlayPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            ZStack {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Text("Text 1")
                        .accessibilityHidden(true)
                    Text("Text 2")
                }
                // ====
                // ==== You need to add this line ====
                // ====
                .accessibilityElement(children: .contain)
                // don't want the view to be accessible when overlay is presented
                .accessibilityHidden(isOverlayPresented)
                
                if isOverlayPresented {
                    Text("Text 3")
                        .padding(30)
                        .background(.yellow)
                }
            }
            
            Button(isOverlayPresented ? "Show" : "Hide") {
                isOverlayPresented.toggle()
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
    }
}
```